# toMapCoordinates() vs toLayerCoordinates()

Tags: qgis, qgsmapcanvas

I am currently using the QGIS C++ libraries to display a map. I am new to QGIS, and wantd to know what the difference between map and layer coordinates is? From what I understand, map gives the coordinates as per the CRS of the canvas. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, map is the canvas, while layer is the individual layer.

And from the API Docs:

toMapCoordinates()

> transformation from screen coordinates to map coordinates

http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapTool.html#af5d1a72453be6d47ab1583d4e71e7e53

toLayerCoordinates()

> transformation from screen coordinates to layer's coordinates

http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapTool.html#a8b39f33854affab69ca560a530856609

Comment: Just to further clarify - screen coordinates are pixels.